# How to Build Sample Android Location App from GitHub

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle

I downloaded the Main branch of the Sample Android Location App from GitHub as a ZIP file.
https://github.com/android/location-samples
Once on my computer, I unzipped the file to a subdir.
Then in Android Studio (4.1.1), I imported the project by specifying the unzip'd dir.
It opens fine, but I am unsure how to build it.
In addition, Studio editor shows several errors such as "Cannot resolve symbol 'AppCompatActivity'".

Not sure how to proceed now to build, test and debug. I am sure it is something simple I am overlooking. I checked the ReadMe. This is the first time I have attempted to download and Build a project from GitHub Android Samples, so just need a couple pointers.

Answer (score 0):

After unzipping the file, you can import it to AS
[image]

Choose the dirrectory with Android icon to open the project

[image]

Then it will download the dependencies, jars, SDKs, etc. After downloading, you can refer to the upper right side, where you can choose which App to build, then click the green arrow, gradle will take care of the rest.

[image]

If it didn't show the green arrow, the gradle sync might have failed, and you can sync the project by click this

[image]

Comment: Thanks PatrickGeng. As stated, I did the "Unzip" and "Import Project" as you show above. However, now I am stuck. My Build Configuration dropdown (your 2nd pic above) only contains "location-samples-main [build]". I don't see what you show. Also, under the File menu (your 3rd pic above) I do NOT have "Sync Project with Gradle Files". What am I missing?

Comment: Hi @JJJones_3860, I add a screenshot of when choose the folder, sometimes the directory of imported project can cause the Sync button disappeared. You can also check the SDK version and path in SDK Manager.

Comment: Thanks PatrickGeng, but this does not help or change anything.